# Sending SOL using messages in web3/solana

Tags: node.js, solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I'm following the Solana docs and trying to send a transaction through message which according to Solana docs is another way to construct a transaction. I have no problem sending the transaction but nowhere I can mention the amount that I want to send. I have been following this [link](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-reference#message) and had a hard time figuring out add amount. I suspected that I can mention the amount like `web3.SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS.Transfer({from, to, lamports})` but apparently it provides me an error and when I look into the web3 library I cannot find `SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS.Transfer`

Can someone please point out how I can add the amount to the transaction instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `SYSTEM_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS.Transfer` has fields where you can provide the instruction along with it you can provide lamports in bigint. This will allow you to transfer the sol using messages

Something like this

```
let layoutFields = Object.assign({ instruction: type.index , lamports : BigInt(amount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)});
```